# Looking for slide bar with two knobs in Java

Tags: java, swing, slider, jfreechart

I am looking for slide bars with two knobs for a user to move them separately or both together, similar to the one in the picture to use in Java. Any sidebar with two knobs (two indicators) would do. Does it exist?

[image]

Comment: Try taking a look at [**this**](http://harmoniccode.blogspot.com.au/2011/11/friday-fun-component-xiv.html).  I've used it in the past and it works well..

Comment: Cool component. This is getting ridiculous. Every question is getting closed.  Somebody tell me how this question should be worded so it doesn't break the idiotic guidelines for asking a question? In 10 years of answering questions on the forums I have no idea where to look to find a component like this. I have no idea what the name of the component would be. Where do I go to get help??? How does pointing a person to a website or library generate opinionated answers?

Comment: Thanks for the support. I am disparately in the need of this answer and these guys closed my question!

Answer (score 1):

That's called a range slider. Here it is discussed in another thread:
[Range Slider in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884112/range-slider-in-java)

Also, here's an API which provides a JRangeSlider swing object: 
http://prefuse.org/doc/api/prefuse/util/ui/JRangeSlider.html

I've never used it, but it looks like just what you want.

Comment: Is there a version with 3 knobs (Left, Center and Right value)?

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest checking out JIDE (open source components), i know for a fact there is a range slider with two knobs

Comment: Is there a version with 3 knobs (Left, Center and Right value)?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late answer:)

I recently implemented JRangeSlider *without custom painting code*, thus it will always look like normal JSlider, but with two knobs.

https://github.com/andronix3/SwingHacks/blob/master/com/smartg/swing/JRangeSlider.java

Comment: Is there a version with 3 knobs (Left, Center and Right value)?